# Outer Join not providing the second table fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to do an OUTER JOIN between table1 and table2. I have successfully merged both of them using raw sql in pgAdmin but when I try to use Flask-SQLAlchemy it does not provide the second table fields. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Raw SQL that successfully gives all the fields:

```
select * 
from company.Table1 
      left outer join company.Table2 
      on company.Table1."Batch ID" = company.Table2.id
```

Flask-SQLAlchemy code that does not provide all the fields:

````
result= session.query(Table1)\  
    .outerjoin(Table2, Table1.batchid == Table2.batchid)\  
    .order_by(asc(Table1.date)).all()  
for x in result:  
    print(x.__dict__)```
````

Comment: Well, the column name changed from `Table2.id` in the first query to `Table2.batchid` in the second one. That could do it.

Comment: @EricBrandt Yes sorry that is because I created the fields in pgAdmin and mapped it after in my classes with the naming being more clear.